# Can't get past the PIN-screen of my newly bought used S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, factory-reset, password

I recently bought a used Samsung Galaxy S4. The problem is that the previous owner did not factory reset is and even after putting in the memory and SIM-card from my old phone, I can’t get past the pin-code screen. I have tried factory resetting it myself, but it isn’t working. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

So you have resetted the device? 
Or was the resetting to factory defaults not working?

Boot into the recovery ( **volume UP + power button** - press both until the screen turns on and release the power button then) and then perform a **factory reset from there**. This should delete all user data and your phone should restart to the initial startup configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the emergency call menu and dial ∗ # ∗ #SERVICE# ∗# ∗ there should be a list item where you can reset the phone to factory settings. 
On my sony it is Customisation Settings > Reset Customisation.